# Unwanted gaps around transparent elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First post here, so please be gentle! I am making an effect which relies on having divs of the same colour (black) and opacity (0.9) next to one another. The divs are re-sized with JS on a mousemove event. This is supposed to create a seamless overlay (I can't just do it with a single overlayed element, because the effect requires a transparent png at the center, with no overlay behind it.) The effect works fine without any transparency applied to the overlay, but when transparency is applied, a tiny gap appears between the divs, ruining the effect, as what is behind the overlay shows through the gaps. The gap is not consistent, but comes and goes as the divs resize, and when the positions of the elements are checked, the numbers returned show the edges of the divs lining up perfectly (which, visually, they do when no opacity is set.) I'm thinking this is a browser bug, as the same effect used to work in older versions of chrome and IE. Is this a known issue, and if so, are there any workarounds? Have searched high and low, but can't seem to find any mention of the issue anywhere, hence the post. Thanks in advance!

Edit - here is a stripped down version of my code:

HTML

```
<div id="contentWrapper">
    <div id="myCursor">
        <div id="cursorTop"></div>
        <div id="cursorBottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#myCursor {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#cursorTop {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    opacity:0.9;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90);
}

#cursorBottom {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    opacity:0.9;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90);
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contentWrapper').mousemove(function(e) {
        $('#cursorTop').css('height', e.clientY);
        $('#cursorBottom').css('height', window.innerHeight - e.clientY);
    });
});
```

Further edit - This stripped down example only seems to show up the problem in Edge, but the full version also has the problem (to a lesser degree) in Chrome

[Here is a screenshot, as requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnK8S.png)

Comment: can you show your code ( a small runnable example) or better yet,  make a jsfiddle or a code snippet

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) We can help you better with code.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my post to include my code, as stripped down as I can make it

Comment: I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3ujpknn/) to test your code, it's working fine. It would be good if you can attach a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks evilReiko, but it's still giving me a problem in Edge. I have tried making the overlay using borders, instead of separate divs. This helps a little, but I still get the gap along the right hand and bottom edges of the central image. I also tried removing transparency from the image, and adding it with CSS, as I thought the browser might be struggling with rendering the two different transparencies next to one another, but that didn't improve the situation. It's driving me nuts!

Comment: I just changed the colours of the two elements in the jsfiddle to #000000, which is what I'm actually using on my page, and the issue shows up there now. You could just make it out with the red and blue, but it wasn't obvious, I'll admit. Serves me right for changing the colours to try to make the issue obvious!

Comment: Just realised I didn't tag people properly, so I'm probably talking to myself, so thanks @evilReiko

Comment: I've just tested that jsfiddle on the ancient IE7, guess what, it's working fine! I don't have Edge, so you're on your own!

Comment: Thanks again @evilReiko. I've actually solved the problem now, completely by accident! It turns out that if I declare a size for my central image, rather than just letting the browser render it at the actual image size, the bug disappears! Joy!